# By what trick separately constructed two objects can be a same object?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I was building my project using nodejs & mongodb & mongoose, and my router for /api/db/* was working perfectly.

db connection code is actually so short that there's no need for separation, but suddenly I became curious if it can be separated.

db-instance.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');

module.exports = mongoose;
```

models.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var fooSchema = mongoose.Schema({ id: Number, content: String })
var Foo = mongoose.model('Foo', fooSchema);

module.exports = {
  Foo: Foo,
  mongoose: mongoose
}
```

db.js

```
var models = require('../db/models'); --- 1
var mongoose = require('../db/db-instance'); --- 2
// importing order does not matter, both 1-2 & 2-1 works

if (mongoose === models.mongoose) {
  console.log('same instance'); // this is printed
} else {
  console.log('different instance');
}

router.get('/getFoos', function(req, res, next) {
  models.Foo.find(...).exec(function(err, foos) {
    if (!err) {
      res.send(foos);
    } else {
      console.log(err);
    }
  })
});
```

It worked perfectly and I thought mongoose module must have checked if it's instantiated already and give a stored instance if it's asked again but was not true.

/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js

```
function Mongoose() {
  ...
}

var mongoose = module.exports = exports = new Mongoose;
```

I was lost at this point.

Answer (score 0):

This functionality is provided by Node, not by the particular modules. From the Node API reference:

> Modules are cached after the first time they are loaded. This means (among other things) that every call to require('foo') will get exactly the same object returned, if it would resolve to the same file. [("Caching")](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_caching)

It is *possible* for the objects occasionally to be different in very particular circumstances, but they will almost always be the same object if they are loaded from the same file.

Comment: wow thank you so much! both for accurate answer and lightning speed :) want to vote up but my reputation is too low... :(

Comment: @Haedaal No worries. Just accept the answer when you can!